# View stolen item status more easily?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking at a list of stolen items in my character's inventory on-person. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to quickly determine which items are stolen or not, without having to hover over each and every item. Is this a bug, or expected behavior? Is there a way of easily seeing the stolen status, without having to hover over each item?

When items are inside of a container, such as a chest, the item's label is red, which is a nice, quick visual indicator that the item is being stolen, should you take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way, is a mod called "Sky-UI". That redoes the interface and makes it very easy to tell the difference. Besides that, your unfortunately stuck with the default menu options. There might be other mods for it as well.  For 360 it would be stuck with the base options.

Comment: Thanks mate - I was hoping to not have to use any mods, but I was considering using SkyUI eventually. Just found out about it a couple days ago.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan Just note that Skyrim Script Extender makes your game very unstable and leads to more crashes than usual.

Comment: Actually it really doesn't. As long as you integrate it nicely, I haven't had any issues with the script extender.  I have played a lot of hours on this game, with the Sky UI, and have yet to have a crash.  There are some performance issues on mine (or were) but that has nothing to do with the script extender. All it basically does is run in the background and add some scripting options.
 
Just to clarify, that is from my personal experience. I have also not noted anything in any of the forums, on the nexus page, or any related site to that affect. It might depend on the mods you have.

Comment: @Assylum i've been using SKSE for a while now, haven't noticed any instability at all.  If you are getting any instability, I'd take a hard look at the mods you have first, and not SKSE.